# How to give access or dismiss to the microphone and camera popup in Chromedriver while running the Selenium test?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have applied the below ChromeOptions but not working for me. Due to this, I am unable to type on the "Enter Pin" input box on the screen.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-user-media-security=true");
dvr = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, visit your app with Chrome and set camera to always allow.

Second, get the [chrome prefs](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Configuration) file

Third, copy the default directory to some path /path/to/defaultconfig

Lastly, add that config path to chrome options before launching the driver:
"user-data-dir=/path/to/defaultconfig"

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

HashMap<String, Integer> preferences = new HashMap<>();
preferences.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic", 1);    # 1:allow, 2:block 
preferences.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera", 1);    # 1:allow, 2:block 

chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);
dvr = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```